# Dask Data Lake is this the right approach?

Tags: dask, dask-dataframe

So I am using Dask to store large amounts of data. We get about 50 million new rows of data a day. Not many columns wide. I currently store the data with ddf.to_parquet(long_term_storage_directory). As I get new data I append this to the long_term_storage_directory directory. Everything works okay but it is slow.

The index that is being used is time I was hoping that as I add data it would simply get added to the long list of parquet files in long_term_storage_directory. (long_term_storage_directory is also index by the same time field) I am worried that the approach I am taking is flawed in some way. Maybe I need to use spark or something else to store the data?

Note: 
The ddf_new_data is indexed with the same indexed used in ddf_long_term_storage_directory.  I was hoping that since the new data comming in has the same index as what is currently in the long_term_storage_directory that added the data to the long term data store would be faster.

```
ddf_long_term_storage_directory = dd.read_parquet(path=long_term_storage_directory, engine='pyarrow')
ddf_new_data = dd.read_parquet(path=directory_to_add_to_long_term_storage, engine='pyarrow')

ddf_new_data = ddf_new_data.set_index(index_name, sorted=False, drop=True)

ddf = dd.concat([ddf_long_term_storage_directory, ddf_new_data], axis=0)
ddf = ddf.repartition(partition_size='200MB') #??? Do I need to do this every time I add new data
ddf.to_parquet(long_term_storage_directory)
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest answer would be to not load the old data/concat/repartition. That indeed will get slower as more data accumulated. Instead, just write the incoming data to a new, sequentially-numbered file in the same directory.